# Android ApiDemos TextAlign not aligning in test program outside of demo program

Tags: android

I cut out the code for the `Graphics->Text Align` activity from the `ApiDemos` for Android, and pasted it into a new activity.  When I run it on larger higher density screens (both on my physical phone, and on a 480x800 emulator), the text does not scale to fill the screen.

I have put the code in `BeyondCompare` and cannot find anything significantly different between the 2 activities, yet when run outside of the `ApiDemos` program, it does not scale properly. When run from the `ApiDemos` program, it scales fine;  I have even made the `TextAlign` activity the only one that runs from the `ApiDemos` and it still scales fine.

I checked the manifests of both programs and there does not appear to be anything that would cause the canvas to stop scaling appropriately.  The activity creates a `SimpleView` class when it starts, so it does not appear to be using XML for the layout.

What am I missing?  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The ApiDemos, even though they are for 2.2, level 8, did not target a specific level in the manifest, thus allowing auto-scaling of the screen.  To get my version to work, I had to remove this line from the Android manifest:
; either that or change it to , so the auto-scaling would work on newer phones.